# Write data in csv file but data are overwritten

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Try to  scrape the data but data are overwrite and they will give the data of only `2 page` in the csv file kindly recommend any solution for that I an waiting for your response How can I fix this? is there any way then suggest me I think due to for loop they overwrite data Thank you. these is the page link  https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/countries/ca/

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from csv import writer


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20) 
for page in range(1,3):             
    URL = 'https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/countries/ca/{page}'.format(page=page)
    driver.get(URL)
    time.sleep(2)

    urls= []
    data = []
    page_links =driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='card__desc']//a[starts-with(@href, '/online')]")
    for link in page_links:
        href=link.get_attribute("href")
        urls.append(href)    
       
  
    with open('product.csv', 'w',newline='',encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        thewriter=writer(csvfile)
        header=['name','url','website_link','company','rating']
        thewriter.writerow(header)
        
        
        for url in urls:
            driver.get(url)
            time.sleep(1)
            
            try:
                name=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h1.review-intro__title").text   
            except:
                pass
            
            try:
                company=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//p[span[contains(.,'Company')]]/following-sibling::div").text   
            except:
                pass
            try:
                link=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//p[span[contains(.,'Website')]]/following-sibling::div").text   
            except:
                pass
            
            try:
                rate=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.rating-ring__number").text
                
            except:
                pass
            
            jobinfo=[name,url,link,company,rate]
            thewriter.writerow(jobinfo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open the same file for (over)writing with `'w'` each time but loop over 3 pages.  Use a different name or use `'a'` (append) instead, but you will get the header three times as well with the current configuration.

Better would be to open the file for writing outside the `for page` loop, write the header, then inside `for page` write the rows.

Basically:

```py
with open('product.csv', 'w',newline='',encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    thewriter=writer(csvfile)
    header=['name','url','website_link','company','rating']
    thewriter.writerow(header)

    for page in range(1,3):             
        ... # compute the row info
        jobinfo=[name,url,link,company,rate]
        thewriter.writerow(jobinfo)
```